# How resizing a 3D image works, intuitively

Tags: python, imaging

I know how resizing works in 2D images but I am having issues understanding how it works in 3D images. As I think a 3D image is made by stacking multiple 2D images in the z dimension. What happens in the z dimension while resizing, is some 2D images are dropped? Looking for some intuitive answer

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. StackOverflow is not the right site to ask this.

Comment: Even though this is not a programming question

I'd suggest you to look at [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

This is what is used for rotate/resize/move 3d geometric objects

Answer (score 1):

Don't imagine 3D images as stacked 2D images - you lose the connection in the Z axis, as you called it. Imagine 3D images instead as a cube made of small cubes, now you can interpolate just like in 2D. Dropping 2D slices would make no sense imho.

There are also many different methods for resizing images, but in 3D, interpolation (the most trivial resising algo not counting nearest neighbors) is definitely possible.

This also means that you're always resizing all three axes - if you're not, the problem can be simplified by splitting it into `N` 2D interpolations (or `N*M` 1D interpolations).